# how to retrieve in _POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, textbox

How to retrieve this one :

```
<form name="payform" method="POST" action="payment.php">
<?php
echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. '" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';                    
?>    
</form>
```

in payment.php

```
<?

$total_pay=$_POST["totalNS"];

echo "Payment gateway simulation! <br>";
echo "Mode : ".$mode."<br>";
echo "Total Payment : ".$total_pay."<br>";

?>
```

how can I retrieve :

```
 echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. '" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';
```

in payment php how can I write `$payment =_POST[eg_payamt_ ?????]`

Payment.php, updated with vardump ?

```
<?php
$mode=$_POST["eg_mode"];
$total_pay=$_POST["totalNS"];
$record_count=$_POST["record"];
$desc=$_POST["eg_desc_".$record_count];
$payamt = $_POST['$eg_payamt_'. $record_count]; 

$k=$record_count=$_POST["record"];

foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
  if(strpos('eg_payamt_', $k) === 0){
    echo "$k => $v\n";
  }
}
echo var_dump($payments);


echo "Payment gateway simulation! <br>";
echo "Mode : ".$mode."<br>";
echo "Total Payment : ".$total_pay."<br>";
echo "Record count : ".$record_count."<br>";

?>
```

how can I use vardump ?? how can I retrieve pay_amt with vardump ?

```
echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. '"
Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';
```

any ideas to get multiple _POST which are being passed??

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

> ```
> <form name="payform" method="POST" action="payment.php">
> <?php
> echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt[]" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';                   
>
> ?>    
> </form>
> ```

In your php:

```
    foreach($_POST["eg_payamt"] as $key => $payamt){
        echo "$key => $payamt\n"; 
    }
```

The problem is you can't set the index of your eg_payamt elements. They are in the same order as in your form.

Answer (score 0):

can do like this

in the form, add another hidden value inside the form to be passed to payment.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="record_count" value="<? echo $record_count ?>" />
```

and in payment.php :

```
$record_count = $_POST['record_count'];
$eg_payamt = $_POST['$eg_payamt_'. $record_count];
```

Comment: if eg_payamt are more than one ??

Comment: how can I create $eg_payamt_xx = $_POST['$eg_payamt_'. $record_count]; ??

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
  if(strpos($k, 'eg_payamt_') === 0){
    $payments[$k] = $v;
  }
}
var_dump($payments);
```

or you can name payments like that

```
echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt[' . $record_count . ']" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';
....
var_dump($_POST['eg_payamt']);
```

Comment: $k=$record_count=$_POST["record"];

Comment: $k=$record_count=$_POST["record"]; ?

Comment: I write in payment.php or the sending form ?

Comment: var_dump($_POST['eg_payamt']);
= NULL ?

Comment: you write html where you use html and php where you use php. You retrive data from form in payment.php so write var_dump() there to see how $_POST look like

Comment: update code above, how can I use vardump ?? how can I retrieve pay_amt with vardump ?

Comment: <?php
                         echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. '" Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>'; 
       var_dump($_POST['eg_payamt']);
                   
     ?>